# Change the ownership of app script project to an account in a different organization

Tags: google-apps-script

I created two editor add-ins using a personal gmail account and now need to move the ownership of the corresponding app-script projects associated with these add-ins to an account in a different organization. The error that I am getting is that you can only move ownership if the account belongs to the same organization.
Please suggest how to get this done.

Answer (score 1):

Transfering the ownership of a file owned by a Gmail account to a G Suite / Google Workspace account  cant' be done.

DISCLAIMER - I didn't tested the following, proceed under your own risk

One option is

1. Share the project with an account from your G Suite / Google Workspace organization
2. Using the organization account, make a copy of the project (Script)
3. Save a version on the copy of the Script
4. Add the Cloud Project ID to the copy of the Script
5. On the Cloud Project, go to the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK replace the old Script id by the new Script id and the old version number by the version number of the copy of the Script